Is Gen 3:15 a prophecy on the Virgin Conception of Jesus?
We see God cursing the devil in Gen 3:15( NKJV):

And I will put enmity Between you and the woman, And between your seed and her Seed; He shall bruise your   head, And you shall bruise His heel.”

Many Versions have the term 'offspring' in place of 'seed'.  Understandably, since Adam excused himself by blaming Eve and she in turn blaming the devil, for the episode of disobedience, one can relate the curse given to devil to Eve' s role. Nevertheless, Adam was also a victim of devil's temptation. God, however chose to relate the curse on devil to women and her seed, not mentioning the seed of man.
In broader sense,the Verse is seen as a fore-picture of the Passion of Christ and his conquering of the devil.
Be that as it may, the term 'seed' needs elaboration. In OT times, when the phenomenon of procreation was not fully understood, males were deemed to be source of the seed of progeny(Ger 31:27).It is doubtful if the role of ovum from the side of the female was ever recognised, though women  took the entire blame in case of not having children !
Given that God placed woman and her seed at the pivot of the curse on devil, is Gen 3:15 a prophecy on the Virgin Conception of Jesus by his Blessed Mother ?

In a single word - No!  Virgins are not mentioned.

It's not at all obvious how everything that precedes it is related to the final line. What reason is there for thinking that it might be such a prophecy?

If Eve was a prophetic picture of the future, the woman would not be Mary, but Israel the nation as seen in Revelation 12.

'Her seed' is seed (a human baby) without the mention of the man. Human seed is an infant. What, exactly, these words mean could not (yet) be revealed but they are perfectly consistent with what we now know. Yes.

Thanks, Nigel J. Would you please develop your comments into an answer ?

I think that @Anne has developed the comment better than I would have done.

There certainly is a link between Genesis 3:15 and the miraculous conception in the virgin Mary's womb. "The seed of the woman" in Genesis 3:15 is an accurate translation of the Hebrew. It is also true that when you say, "the term 'seed' needs elaboration", that needs to be addressed, but I leave all that to those who are qualified. All I want to do here is show some connections between Genesis 3:15, "the woman" of Revelation chapter 12, and the virgin Mary. She is certainly included in all of that, though others are also. This "seed" is a major biblical topic.
Mary was the culmination of a long line of descent. Other women came before, leading up to Jesus Christ. Sarah had an important part in that, detailed near the end of this answer. And that line went all the way back to Eve. Jesus being "true God and eternal life" (1 John 5:20), must be the seed promised to Eve, for she is mystically designated 'The mother of all living', Genesis 3:20.
And if he be the seed of the woman Eve, then the visionary woman of Revelation 12:1-2 must at least encompass that truth, however it may be further developed throughout scripture. The serpent's head shall be stamped underfoot by the living seed of the woman. No wonder then, that the symbolic great red dragon "stood before the woman, for to devour her child as soon as it was born" (Rev. 12:4). The next verse speaks of this man child being caught up unto God and to his throne - surely this signifies the incarnation in a mystical way? Likewise, mention of "the remnant of her seed" indicates more to this mystery than the incarnate Christ.
It does seem clear that Mary was the visible earthly culmination of a heavenly series of visionary prophecies spanning the whole of time, with transcendent expression in Rev. ch. 12. This visionary heavenly woman includes Mary, just as it does Eve, but this glorious vision goes beyond any individual.
Regarding the seed of Genesis 3:15, this was not to be begotten by Adam through the woman, as was Cain, but in a mystery, begotten of God without Adam. The seed of Adam, through Cain, was called the seed of the serpent. That of the woman, begotten of God without Adam, is called the seed of God. See John 8:41-45 and 1 John 3:8-10.
Sarah is shown in Galatians 4:26 to correspond with Jerusalem above, which is free, 'the mother of us all'. This heavenly Jerusalem agrees with the great sign of the heavenly woman bearing Christ the firstborn, and in him all the elect seed from before the foundation of the world. So Christ "the firstfruits - which is what is seen in Revelation 12:1-2 & 5 - "afterward they that are Christ's at his coming (1 Cor. 15:23), "the remnant of her seed" as in Revelation 12:17.
Much of this has been explained in the book I now quote from, just giving this summary paragraph:

"In fine, the great sign of the heavenly woman in the vision of
Revelation chapter 12 depicts her as the symbol of that reality, that
heavenly totality of divine thoughts, which brought Christ down from
heaven. She is the origin of his coming forth, the opening of truth
which was the cause of his being born as man. Out of the womb of
ancient, lingering, divine promise, truth, and purpose, nothing but
the coming of Christ yielded fulfilment and brought consummation to
its fulness... In a word, she is the concept that bore Christ and his
seed, called heavenly Jerusalem, and spiritual Zion." The Revelation
of Jesus Christ, p 288, John Metcalfe
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Yes, certainly, the virgin Mary is intrinsically part of that and the prophecy of Genesis 3:15.

Very edifying indeed. Up-voted +1.

Let me add something important to Anne's excellent answer.
Notice that the word, seed, in English is, unfortunately, and invariant plural such as deer, fish, squid, bison, sheep, and so on. The exception in a few cases is for kinds of fish/fishes, etc. Yes, English thrives on paradox and ambiguity.
Seed as an invariant plural has led to some erroneous ideas from people unfamiliar with Paul's clarification in Galatians:

Now the promises were spoken to Abraham and to his seed. He does not
say, “And to seeds,” as referring to many, but rather to one, “And to
your seed,” that is, Christ. - Galatians 3:16 NASB

Here's how the literal Hebrew reads in Genesis 3:15. Notice that "seed" is a masculine singular, the reference to the serpent is masculine singular, but the reference to Eve is feminine singular, which is very strange given the ancient concept that males planted their seed into females.

This singular-form of seed continues in the rest of the verse regarding the prophecy of bruising head and heel. Eve as having seed would be miraculous, which provides credibility to the virgin birth as the prophesied seed (singular) of Eve.

Eve as having seed would be miraculous - no, it wouldn't. In Gen 16:10 Hagar also is promised that her seed will be blessed by YHVH.

Again, in that culture, "seed" was considered the man's contribution and refers to his descendants. You could argue that since Abraham was the father of Ishmael, the angel wanted to distinguish between the offspring of Abraham and the offspring of Hagar here.

That's a very important point about 'seed' being singular with regard to Gen.3:15, backed up with examining the Hebrew language. +1
